# Magento 2, rerwite entire core module

Tags: magento2, overrides, core

I need to rewrite newsletter module. I nedd to add some fields to database and grid. And I need to change the form.
What is the best way to do it in magento2? Shoud I add fields to newsletter_subscriber table, or should I use eav attributes?
There is any tutorial or example how to rewrite entire core module in magento 2?

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 options here.
You either disable completely the core newsletter module when installing Magento and build your own module based on the same functionality but with your own table schema and logic.
Or you can create a module that extends the core newsletter module.
You can create an upgrade script that adds columns to the newsletter subscriber table and use plugins or rewrites to change the functionality of the models and controllers (and blocks).
There is no EAV involved in the newsletter module I think.

I would go with the second approach.